# Attaching and Sending files with PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php

I need to make a form on my website that allows users to upload and send files. The form has 3 fields, Name, Email and Attachment.

I need all these 3 fields to be sent to me with the file attached to my email once the user clicks Send.

I have 3 files, the HTML file containing the form:

```
<div class="span6 control-group">
    <label>File Upload:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
</div>
```

A .js file containing some visual effects for when the file is sent, if there is an error, required fields

```
var Contact = {
    initialized: false,
    initialize: function() {
        if (this.initialized) return;
        this.initialized = true;
        this.build();
        this.events();
    },
    build: function() {
        this.validations();
    },
    events: function() {
    },
    validations: function() {
        $("#contactForm").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "php/upload-form.php",
                    data: {
                        "name": $("#contactForm #name").val(),
                        "email": $("#contactForm #email").val(),
                        "quote": $("#contactForm #upload_file").val()
                    }, // Rest is visual effects, then ends with //

Contact.initialize();
```

And finally the upload-form.php

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));
header('Content-type: application/json');
require 'php-mailer/class.phpmailer.php';
$to = 'xxx@xxx.xxx';
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
if($to) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $fields = array(
        0 => array(
            'text' => 'Name',
            'val' => $_POST['name']
        ),
        1 => array(
            'text' => 'Email address',
            'val' => $_POST['email']
        ),
        2 => array(
            'text' => 'File',
            'val' => $_POST['file_upload']
        )
    );
    $message = "";
    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $message .= $field['text'].": " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
    }
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();                                      
    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];
    $mail->AddAttachment = $_POST['file_uploaded'];               // attachment
    $mail->AddAddress($to);                               // Add a recipient
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $name);
);
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Body = $name;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
       $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
    }
```

I searched everywhere, everything I got was people saying to add a

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
```

but it doesn't seem to work, the only answers I found on google were to attach files already on the server, but I want to attach files uploaded by users and then sent to my email, and if possible i want the files to be a temp file.

I'm a noob with PHP, so please help me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: refer http://www.excellentwebworld.com/send-file-in-email-attachment-on-form-submit-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

This should work to grab the file attachment and send it to your email

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
```

in `$_FILES()` the `['upload']` keyword represents the name of your file input. So adjust that accordingly.

If you want to send yourself an attachment with the actual attachment name, try this.

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['upload']['name']);
```

What I've found to work pretty easy is set `$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']` and `$_FILES['upload']['name']` as a variables.

So,

```
$file = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']
$file_name = $_FILES['upload']['name']
$mail->AddAttachment($file, $file_name );
```